# Can set either alignment or font, but not both, for NSTextField

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield, nsattributedstring

I have a panel nib with an outlet for one of its textfields, which is set in the nib to have centered alignment. When I display the panel, I would like this textfield to be bolded.
Since NSTextField is a subclass of NSControl, it can use the setAttributedStringValue method and take an attributed string. So I incorporated a bold font like this:

```
NSFont *fontBolded = [NSFont fontWithName:@"Baskerville Bold" size:12.0f];
NSDictionary *dictBoldAttr = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:fontBolded forKey:NSFontAttributeName];   
NSString *sHelloUser = NSLocalizedString(@"Hello User", @"Hello User");
NSAttributedString *attrsHelloUser = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString: sHelloUser attributes:dictBoldAttr];
[self.fooController.tfPanelCenteredField setAttributedStringValue:attrsHelloUser];  
[attrsHelloUser release];
```

The bolding shows up OK, but the field is now left-aligned.

I tried adding a setAlignment, but it had no effect:

```
[self.fooController.tfPanelCenteredField setAlignment:NSCenterTextAlignment];
```

So I tried adding a centered parapraph style to the attributed string’s attributes:

```
NSFont *fontBolded = [NSFont fontWithName:@"Baskerville Bold" size:12.0f];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];   
[paragStyle setAlignment:NSCenterTextAlignment]; 
NSDictionary *dictBoldAttr = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:paragStyle, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, fontBolded, NSFontNameAttribute, nil];
NSString *sHelloUser = NSLocalizedString(@"Hello User", @"Hello User");
NSAttributedString *attrsHelloUser = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString: sHelloUser attributes:dictBoldAttr];
[self.fooController.tfPanelCenteredField setAttributedStringValue:attrsHelloUser];  
[attrsHelloUser release];
[paragStyle release];
```

Now the textfield is centered again, but the bolding is gone. It’s as though the attributed string can accept one *and only one* attribute setting. Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a typo in your code. `NSFontNameAttribute` should be `NSFontAttributeName`.

So your attributes dictionary is:

```
    NSFont *fontBolded = [NSFont fontWithName:@"Baskerville Bold" size:12.0f];
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];   
    [paragStyle setAlignment:NSCenterTextAlignment]; 
    NSDictionary *dictBoldAttr = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  fontBolded, NSFontAttributeName,
                                  paragStyle, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName,
                                  nil];
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm sorry for wasting your time with this, but I never would have figured it out, because the code sense colors the typo as though it were valid. (P.S. Why do those keys have "name" in them at all? Wouldn't "NSFontAttribute" and "NSParagraphStyleAttribute" make more sense?)

Comment: I see now that NSFontNameAttribute is an attribute of NSFontDescriptor, and it's a string for the font name. But NSAttributedString's NSFontAttributeName is for a *font*, not a fontName string, so it's bound to cause confusion.